# Return values from a different row based off one column equalling another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date        Operator 1    Competitor      Price          Sales        
1/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             100
1/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             110
2/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             105
2/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             103
3/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             120
3/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             130
```

My desired output is to create two new columns, of the competitors price and sales for that day:

```
Date        Operator 1    Competitor      Price          Sales        C.Price   C.Sales  
1/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             100           25         110
1/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             110           25         100
2/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             105           25         103
2/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             103           25         105
3/1/2021      Store1      Store2           15             120           25         130
3/1/2021      Store2      Store1           25             130           25         120
```

How can I lookup the `Competitor` within `Operator 1` and return those values? I can do it in excel (via VLOOKUP) but not sure in pandas. Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I am trying to lookup from within the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [pandas.DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) can do what you want

```py
merged = pd.merge(df, df, left_on=['Date', 'Operator 1'], right_on=['Date', 'Competitor'])
```

```
       Date Operator 1_x Competitor_x  Price_x  Sales_x Operator 1_y Competitor_y  Price_y  Sales_y
0  1/1/2021     Store1       Store2       15      100     Store2       Store1       25      110
1  1/1/2021     Store2       Store1       25      110     Store1       Store2       15      100
2  2/1/2021     Store1       Store2       15      105     Store2       Store1       25      103
3  2/1/2021     Store2       Store1       25      103     Store1       Store2       15      105
4  3/1/2021     Store1       Store2       15      120     Store2       Store1       25      130
5  3/1/2021     Store2       Store1       25      130     Store1       Store2       15      120
```

After that, drop unnecessary columns and rename columns to what you want with

```py
merged.drop(['Operator 1_y', 'Competitor_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
merged.rename({'Operator 1_x': 'Operator 1', 'Competitor_x': 'Competitor', 'Price_x': 'Price', 'Price_y': 'CPrice', 'Sales_x': 'Sales', 'Sales_y': 'CSales'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: great - is there a way to specify what columns you want to bring through first? i have a list  `cols` of 20-30 columns I want to bring in. Something like
`merged = pd.merge(df, df[cols], left_on=['Date', 'Operator 1'], right_on=['Date', 'Competitor'])`?

Comment: @SOK I don't understand what do you mean by saying 'bring through first'. But `merged = pd.merge(df, df[cols], left_on=['Date', 'Operator 1'], right_on=['Date', 'Competitor'])` looks ok with me.

Comment: thanks, yeah i just meant specify the columns before the merge